# Is there a usable rendering context in sinatra/padrino?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I am attempting to use the [Exhibit pattern](http://objectsonrails.com/#ID-2656c30c-080a-4a4e-a53e-4fbaad39c262) in a padrino application but to do so properly I need to access the rendering context. That is, I need to have some object `context` such that calling something along the lines of `context.render('accounts/index')` will produce identical output to when `render 'accounts/index'` is called from inside a controller (assuming that all variables are set the same and that `app/views/accounts/index.erb` is a template file).

I can't find anything that does this within the padrino public API, so I attempted to dig deeper. The existing `render` method in the controller wraps sinatra's `render` method, which is a private instance method. So it's not obviously not defined on the class `MyApp` (i.e. the `Padrino::Application` subclass). `MyApp.new` results in an instance of `Rack::Session::Cookie` rather than of itself, and none of the padrino methods that I can find return the existing instance of the app, which would be a suitable candidate for the `context` object if I called its private `render` method.

Is this something that's just inherently too difficult to bother with given sinatra's and padrino's designs, or is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that the answer was in the Objects on Rails book if only I'd kept reading. I needed to pass the context explicitly from within the template: `exhibit(object, self)` inside the template causes the template's rendering context to be passed as the second argument. Of course.

I guess this really wasn't specific to padrino after all and I was looking for something complicated when the answer was very simple.